# Converting string to int fails

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert the string to int with stringstream, the code down below works, but if i use a number  more then **1234567890**, like **12345678901** then it return **0** back ...i dont know how to fix that, please help me out

```
std:: string number= "1234567890";

int Result;//number which will contain the result

std::stringstream convert(number.c_str()); // stringstream used for the conversion initialized with the contents of Text

if ( !(convert >> Result) )//give the value to Result using the characters in the string
    Result = 0;

printf ("%d\n", Result);
```

Comment: You don't need the `.c_str()` there.

Comment: `12345678901` is too large for an `int`, hence the conversion fails.

Comment: Hint: try `#include <limits>` and `std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << std::endl;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, lots of **disinformation** in the existing four or five answers.

An `int` is minimum 16 bits, and with common desktop system compilers it’s usually 32 bits (in all Windows version) or 64 bits. With 32 bits it has maximum 2<sup>32</sup> distinct values, which, setting K=2<sup>10</sup> = 1024, is 4·K<sup>3</sup>, i.e. roughly 4 billion. Your nearest calculator or Python prompt can tell you the exact value.

A `long` is minimum 32 bits, but that doesn’t help you for the current problem, because in all extant Windows variants, including 64-bit Windows, `long` is 32 bits…

So, for better range than `int`, use **`long long`**. It’s minimum 64 bits, and in practice, as of 2012 it’s 64 bits with all compilers. Or, just use a `double`, which, although not an integer type, with the most common implementation (IEEE 754 64-bit) can represent integer values exactly with, as I recall, about 51 or 52 bits  –  look it up if you want exact number of bits.

Anyway, remember to *check the stream for conversion failure*, which you can do by `s.fail()` or simply `!s` (which is equivalent to `fail()`, more precisely, the stream’s explicit conversion to `bool` returns `!fail()`).

Comment: OP didn't specify Windows, so although it was evident that the platform wasn't ILP64 it could have been either LP64 or LLP64, meaning `long` was a feasible answer.

Comment: Also, OP's code is checking the fail status: `if ( !(convert >> Result) )`

Comment: @ecatmur: thanks for pointing out the checking in the OP's code. I didn't look very closely at the code at all. You correctly identified what I considered to be disinformation in your answer, namely the advice to use `long`, which, since `long` is just 32 bits on the most common system (Windows), is ungood: if more than 32 bits are needed, use a type that guarantees more than 32 bits, and not one that might or might not have more.

Answer (score 2):

the maximum number an int can contain is slightly more than 2 billion. (assuming ubiquitios 32 bit ints)

It just doesn't fit in an int!

Comment: should i use long instead or what?

Comment: Depends on the compiler. Sometimes a long is 32 bit (windows!). `long long` will be 64 bit almost everywhere.

Comment: @user1552972: You won't get a useful answer about what you should do unless you tell us what your requirements are. (And, in this case, it would help to know what platform you're using.)

Answer (score 2):

The largest unsigned int (on a 32-bit platform) is 2^32 (4294967296), and your input is larger than that, so it's giving up. I'm guessing you can get an error code from it somehow. Maybe check `failbit` or `badbit`?

```
int Result;
std::stringstream convert(number.c_str());
convert >> Result;
if(convert.fail()) {
    std::cout << "Bad things happened";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a 32-bit or LP64 64-bit system then int is 32-bit so the largest number you can store is approximately 2 billion. Try using a long or long long instead, and change "%d" to "%ld" or "%lld" appropriately.

Comment: Or `int64_t` if you want to be really explicit.

Comment: change "%d" to "%ld" or "%lld".

Answer (score 1):

The (usual) maximum value for a signed int is 2.147.483.647 as it is (usually) a 32bit integer, so it fails for numbers which are bigger.

if you replace `int Result;` by `long Result;` it should be working for even bigger numbers, but there is still a limit. You can extend that limit by factor 2 by using `unsigned` integer types, but only if you don't need negative numbers.

Comment: it seems that you are experiencing overflows which suggest that the type you use just isn't big enough. Check for the actual size by printing sizeof(int) or sizeof(long). The result is the number of bytes that this type can store. For the input "1234567890", which is rougly 2^34 you'll need a type with at least 5 bytes (usually you'll only get 8 as the next bigger thing after int)